# return paginate_comments_links() as array

Tags: array, paginate-comments-links, twitter-bootstrap

The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) specifies:

> type
>       (string) (optional) Controls format of the returned value. Possible values are:
>
> - 'plain' - A string with the links separated by a newline character.
> - 'array' - An array of the paginated link list to offer full control    of display.

In order to add twitter bootstrap pagination styling to the wordpress comments pagination, I want to have the return be an array.

When I add $args to the call, i get no return.

My Code:

```
<ol class="commentlist" style="list-style: none;">
    <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=advanced_comment'); ?>
</ol>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
    $args = array(
    'base'         => '%_%',
    'format'       => '?page=%#%',
    'total'        => 1,
    'current'      => 0,
    'show_all'     => False,
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 2,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'type'         => 'array',
    'add_args'     => False,
    'add_fragment' => ''
    ); 
    paginate_comments_links($args); 
    ?> 
</div>
```

Is this because I am using a custom callback for `wp_list_comments`?

My `advanced_comment()` callback:

```
<?php
function delete_comment_link($id)
{
    if (current_user_can('edit_post'))
    {
    echo '<a href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=cdc&c=$id").'" class="btn btn-default">del</a> ';
    echo '<a href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=cdc&dt=spam&c=$id").'" class="btn btn-default">spam</a>';
    }
} 
function advanced_comment($comment, $args, $depth)
{
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php comment_author(); ?> says: <?php echo substr(get_comment_excerpt(), 0, 25) . "..."; ?></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-1">
            <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='75',$default='<path_to_url>' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
            <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
            <br />
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="comment-text col-md-10">
            <div class="comment-meta">
                <?php echo get_comment_author_link($comment->ID); ?>
            </div>
            <small>
                <?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?>
            </small>             
                <?php comment_text() ?>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group float-right">
            <?php echo get_comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'], 'before' => "<span class='btn btn-default'>", 'after' => '</span>'))) ?>
            <?php delete_comment_link(get_comment_ID()); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>   
<?php 
}
```

Please note: `paginate_comments_links()` works fine if I do not pass it `$args`.

Solution:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php 
        $pages = paginate_comments_links( array( 'echo' => false, 'type' => 'array' ) );
        foreach($pages as $page)
        {
        echo "<li>" . $page . "</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to say would be, you can't say you haven't been warned - see codex page [paginate_comments_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links#Defaults), section »Defaults«:

> These arguments are mostly to make the call of `paginate_links()` work, so **be careful if you change them**.

It's true, [paginate_comments_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links) is pretty much just a already customized version for comments of [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), with those defaults to make this work:

> - 'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
> - 'format' => ,
> - 'total' => $max_page,
> - 'current' => $page,
> - 'echo' => true,
> - 'add_fragment' => '#comments'

What you're doing is overriding the necessary - hence the warning - defaults of `paginate_comment_links()` with the defaults of `paginate_links()`, which leads to the comment links not working anymore. If I'm seeing it correctly the only parameter you want to change is `type`, so this is the only one you have to pass.

Like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'type' => 'list' 
);
paginate_comments_links( $args );
```

Or:

```
paginate_comments_links( array( 'type' => 'list' ) );
```